# Remove Fancytree Dotted Border

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I've got what I think is a basic question, but I can't seem to figure out/find the answer...

I'm looking to use the Fancytree plugin, and am wondering if someone can tell me how I can get rid of the dotted gray border line that shows up around the whole tree?

You can see what I mean in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8sdy3r?p=preview)

```
<body>
<h1>Fancytree Demo</h1>
<button id="button1">Test</button>
<hr>
<div id="tree"></div>
</body>
```

and for some reason it's NOT visible in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mar10/KcxRd/)

```
<div id="tree"></div>
<div id="statusLine">-</div>
<p><button id="button1">Select item2</button></p>
```

I've tried different things, but I can't seem to get rid of it. Anyone have an idea I can try, or point me at what I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the styling of the fancytree border by setting css properties of the `ul.fancytree-container` declaration:

```
ul.fancytree-container {
    border: none;
}
```

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcxRd/1112/) has an updated example without the dotted border.

Comment: And I'm looking at all these simple answers with ".fancytree-container" and clenching my teeth, because I've put the tree in the dialog and nothing seems to work. Geez...

Answer (score 0):

with jquery and after tree is initialized:

```
$(".fancytree-container").css('border','none');
```